# What's the risk of defining Firebase Realtime Database rules as public?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Documentation advises not to do so, but what if I make a part of the database publically readable and writeable? What harm could it cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone who knows the name of your project could read and write the data in your database at those locations.  The name of your project is generally public information to anyone who has a copy of your Android, iOS, or web app.

Obviously, this could cause problem with the data in your app.  Also, if your project has billing enabled, you could end up paying for all the storage and bandwidth that could be used by a potential malicious attacker.